# Weblog doesn't show any entries

Tags: ee1

First I'm glad to join this community!
I'm experiencing very weird problem: 
using EE 1.68 in a template I'm trying to display entries from a weblog, but always got one entry and one specific. I tried adding new ones, checked the expiration dates, statuses, even created new weblog with default settings - same result. I'm using dynamic off and no limits - see below:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="banners" dynamic="off"}
  {title}
  {/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Does anybody experienced some problem? The actual site was moved on a new hosting. Everything worked fine before.

Note* If I open some of the older entries with status closed - it instantly shows??

Comment: In the weblog settings have you assigned a status group to the banner weblog? What happens if you add status="open" to the entries tag?

Comment: If the old ones display instantly, then it maybe a server date versus post date issue. For example if you were posting from California and the server is located in New York, depending on how date settings are set, you may have to wait 3hrs to see a post.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend experimenting with some parameters to the entries tag and see whether you start to see what you are expecting.  Specifically I would start with `status="open"` and `limit="10"` (one at a time) to see if any of those affect what you get out.  You probably also want to turn on template debugging and see what comes out there.  If you really want to see what the entries tag gets if status isn't affecting it at all you can do something like `status="not undefined"` (assuming you haven't defined a status named undefined)

Comment: I did some experiments and suddenly entries came up. It is still weird for me and it's probably a server issue as I did these experiments (excluding the template debugging) before this post.

Comment: They are came up after one refresh - really weird as I mentioned.
Many thinks for the advice UltraBob and you guys, who read my post. Thank you for the help. 
I'm really happy to be part of this community!